# Дозапись в текстовый файл

Tags: c#

Не могу понять как модернизировать код, чтобы сделать дозапись в файл без использования проверки на существование файла.

```
private static void ToCreateFileLogs(string logs)
{
    string path = "logs.txt";
    Stream stream;

    using (stream = File.Open(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.WriteLine(logs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему не просто [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.appendalltext(v=vs.110).aspx)? Цитата: "Добавляет указанную строку в файл, создавая файл, если он не существует."

Comment: *сделать до запись в файл* Наверное, `File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)`... *без использования проверки на существования файла* А куда дописывать-то, если его нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать файл, если его нет, дописать в конец, если он есть:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
```

Или передать в конструктор [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) в вашем примере `true` вторым параметром:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pathToFile, append: true))
{
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    writer.WriteLine(logs);
}
```

Comment: Второй вариант ведь не будет работать если файл не существует, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Winteriscoming если файла нет, он его создаст.